# can't get bluetooth audio working while using chromecast despite setting

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio, chromecast, vlc

i am using a pixel 5a/android 13 to cast to a 1st generation chromecast, using the system wide screen cast available in settings because subtitles don't work when using vlc's casting.  i'm casting to an acer k330 projector but want the audio to go to a tribit xsound go that is bluetoothed.  i can find a setting that says "play vlc audio through tribit," but it still sends the audio to the chromecast/projector.  how do i get it to go to the tribit?